# Web Worker doesn't work with localhost on chrome, but it works with localhost on chrome developer

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I got an example of a  Web Worker (the code below) on google.
I know

> Chrome doesn't let you load web workers when running scripts from a local file.

So, I tried it on my localhost running a Nodejs http-server but it just works in the "Chrome Developer", although it didn't work in "Chrome".

```
    //main.js
    var w; //the variable of object for web worker

    function startWorker() {
        if (typeof (Worker) != "undefined") //checking if browser supports web worker
        {
            if (typeof (w) == "undefined") {
                w = new Worker("js/worker.js");
            }
            w.onmessage = function (e) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = e.data;
            };
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Your browser doesnot support HTML5 Web Worker! :)"; // or display the message that web worker is not supported!
        }
    }

    function endWorker() {
        w.terminate();
    }

    //worker.js
    var i = 0;

    function timedCount() {
        i = i + 1;
        postMessage(i);
        setTimeout("timedCount()", 500);
    }

    timedCount();
```

Please help me to understand.

Comment: Do you have any error in the js console or network panel of your dev-tools? Also I don't know where you got this quote from but what Chrome doesn't let you do is to start a Worker from an external file on the file:// protocol. You can actually load Workers from blobURI or dataURI even though the main page page is loaded from the file:// protocol.

Comment: in the first time, i've started web worker from file on the file://, but after i knew chrome will not allow it, i changed to localhost://. and it just woroked in dev-tool. I have not known why :(

Comment: Hi, I know that: it is the w3schools demo. I tried to run it on an Apache web server (XAMPP Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/8.0.0) and the demo works fine. I created a subfolder in htdocs and I placed the .js script and .htm inside: I executed the .htm file in localhost. So, does it works with nodejs and chrome in developer mode?